# is it possible to catch Exception in Android?

Tags: android, exception, android-bluetooth

Recently I modified my Android code for Android-12.
I was not having android-12 related bluetooth connect permissions for my API. So I handled as below :

```
public List<BluetoothDevice> getHfpDevices() {
    List<BluetoothDevice> hfpConnectedDevs = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        if (mHeadsetService != null) {
            hfpConnectedDevs = mHeadsetService.getConnectedDevices();
        }
    } catch (SecurityException ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Security Exception in Android-12", ex);
    }
    return hfpConnectedDevs;
}
```

Does this catch the securityException thrown when this API is accessed ? or do I need to handle the Exception itself ?

```
catch (Exception ex) {
```

PS : I don't want to add the requestPermission flow as of now. I just need to solve the exception raised when this API is called

Comment: If you are 100% sure that the exception caught will be a `SecurityException` then you can use that in the `catch` block, but if there are multiple types of Exception that could be thrown then either catch all of them or use the base `Exception` class to handle all of them.

Comment: If you are eager to use `try-catch` block in everywhere you touch the Bluetooth API, then why not?